# Convert jquery to javascript - When i scroll down to specific area (Div ID) load HTML Content one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code, When i scroll down to specific area (Div ID) load HTML Content one time.

Actually is working with jQuery, but i want in JavaScript only, without jQuery

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if (checkVisible($("#target"))) {
        $("#something").html(
            `HTML CONTENT`
        );

        $(window).off("scroll");
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
});

function checkVisible(elm, eval) {
    eval = eval || "object visible";
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(), 
        scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop(),  
        y = $(elm).offset().top,
        elementHeight = $(elm).height();

    if (eval == "object visible")
        return (
            y < viewportHeight + scrolltop && y > scrolltop - elementHeight
        );
    if (eval == "above") return y < viewportHeight + scrolltop;
}
```

any suggestions

Comment: Use intersection observer for this. Can provide link/example after the weekend :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/larico/s9omLp6a/5/

working with jquery, i need in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', () => {
    if( checkVisible( document.getElementById('target'))) {
        document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = 'HTML CONTENT';

        window.off('scroll');
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
} )

function checkVisible(elm, eval) {
    eval = eval || "object visible";
    var viewportHeight = window.height;
    var scrolltop = window.scrollTop();
    var y = elm.offset().top;
    var elementHeight = elm.height;

    if (eval == "object visible")
        return (
            y < viewportHeight + scrolltop && y > scrolltop - elementHeight
        );
    if (eval == "above") return y < viewportHeight + scrolltop;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i create a codepen,  https://codepen.io/netlarico/pen/WaLLEM  
with your lines, it does not work still. :(

Comment: Are your elements id's set to those values?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: window.height is not a function

Comment: sorry i missed your reply I updated the answer, sorry its been almost a year.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `.on()` function (when dom not modified) replace `addEventListener()`

The jQuery element selectors (`#target` or `#something`) you can replace by `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()` functions.

The `scrollTop` property avalilable on the scrollable element without jQuery (but not function, it is only a property)

The jQuery `.html()` function can replace by `element.innerHTML='...'` one